# Linux Server Update Windows Server DNS (DHCP Not Windows)

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

I have Linux machines that are DHCP clients that have send hostname enabled but are not updating DNS on the Windows servers.

DHCP is coming from the firewall, NOT Windows. Other windows machines update their DNS entries fine (they're on the domain), however I have unauthorized DNS updates enabled.

DHCP on the firewall is serving up the Windows DNS servers are DNS entries, not proxying it.

Am I missing something? I'd like to avoid installing Samba on all of the Linux boxes.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, try to join domain, if you don't want add linux boxes into Domain, add A records manually in DNS, and try they are resolving. Try clear cache, scavenging settings check.

I think so there is no issue in joining domain.

Thanks

Anil Kumar